# Randomly add or subtract a number between two numbers from a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to randomly either add or subtract a number between two values (also random) to a range of cells using vba? I'm unsure how to get both to be random.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you wanting to add/subtract the **same** random number from every cell, or add/subtract a **different** random number from each cell?  And is the `between two values (also random)` comment implying that the upper and lower bounds could be any numbers between negative infinity and positive infinity, or are there limits on those numbers?

Comment: The same random number. And, this is going to be done with a button press, so as long as the next time its pressed it should be a different random number than the first.

Comment: These numbers will just be two integers like 2 and 70.

Comment: But would `2 and 70` sometimes be `-500 and 23618276187`?

Comment: The result of which could be something like this yes, as the existing integers do contain a 0 and a negative number already.

Comment: I'm not sure what picking two random number (without bounds) to act as the bounds for picking another random number would imply - I think it means that the final random number still ends up being anywhere between negative infinity and positive infinity.  I think you are going to have to have bounds somewhere or else the operation just makes no sense.

Comment: For a fixed range `[a,b]` there is a default notion of random ( the uniform distribution on `[a,b]`) but there is no default notion of random on `a` and `b` themselves if they can be arbitrary real numbers subject only to the constraint that `a < b`. Do you want them normally distributed? If so, with what mean and standard deviation? Some other distribution? Whatever it is, you need to specify more.

Comment: @YowE3K If you pick two random numbers c,d in a range [a,b] and then you pick a random number between c and d, the result is of course a number between a and b, but the distribution of such numbers is noticeably biased towards the midpoint and away from the endpoints of [a,b], as simple experiments show. Not quite clear what OP has in mind as they have never clarified.

Comment: @JohnColeman - My mind can cope with the idea of a random number, but it really starts to hurt when I think of a random number selected between two randomly selected (without bounds?) numbers.  And I (and people in our Actuarial department) couldn't really see what the practical purpose of it would be.

Comment: @YowE3K This particular example seems a bit odd, but in the Bayesian approach to probability and statistics it is somewhat common to think of the parameters of a probability model to themselves be random variables drawn from some hyperdistribution (also called a prior distribution). My head also starts to hurt when I go too far down that rabbit hole. See this if you are curious: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter (OP never spelled out their hyperparameters or even their model).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without VBA. `=RANDBETWEEN(-10,10)` generates a random number between -10 and 10. Store that in a cell and use a formula to add the same random number to any of your values. Use the Randbetween function directly in a formula to generate a new random number for each operation.

Similarly in VBA, generate a random number and store in a variable. Use the variable to calculate the result with the range in a loop. Or use the random number in the calculation with the range directly to use a different random number in each iteration of the loop.

Edit:

- B2 has a random negative number
- B3 has a random positive number
- B5 has a random number between these two
- column D has a range of integers
- column E has a formula that adds/subtracts the same random number to all integers in the range.

To refresh, hit F9

[image]

Comment: But that makes the random value to be selected between 0 and 10 (and then randomly added or subtracted) but the question is to have both 0 and 10 be random.

Comment: Use your imagination. You can nest a Rand() function inside the Randbetween to make the start and stop values random, too.

Comment: Also I may not have been totally clear, the cells that I plan to alter will already have integers in them, and I would like to add or subtract a random number to these values which already exist

Comment: I don't think the distribution will be the same, e.g. if the random upper and lower bounds were 10 and 4, then +/- 2 is not a valid value.

Comment: I posted a screenshot.